# What's the meaning of "You last voted on this answer x min. ago." box?

Tags: support

I've voted for an answer (upvote indicator and counter changed accordingly)

After some browsing on SE I returned on the question page, and I saw that there was no upvote arrow and the counter showed the "wrong" value. So I re-clicked on the upvote, and this message appeared.

Is it my fault? Or just a glitch in the Matrix?

[image]

Comment: I cannot confirm, I just cant look at logs for voting to confirm bugs such as these, but I have had it happen when I cleared my vote after voting and then later changed my mind, it recognizes my no-vote as my last action and it has been too long without an edit to correct. Was resolved by a superfluous edit(which I do not promote ;p) and voting again.

Comment: Why aren't we allowed to change our minds after some amount of time, even if the post has not changed?

Comment: @OlinLathrop: You can, but only for a small amount of time. Why? Because there is no use case for it. It's unlikely that an answer you originally upvoted thirty minutes ago will suddenly appear worthy of a downvote now. If a better answer comes along, it doesn't make the original one wrong. In the event that an answer is later proven wrong, you need to comment to the author anyway to change it (in which case you can revote) or delete it.

Comment: Leave a comment explaining why it's wrong, and others will downvote it. You could even edit the answer yourself, though hopefully you edit it to be correct, as opposed to editing it to show its flaws more clearly.

Comment: @SimpleCoder Actually there is a use case for changing votes. Sometimes the offered solution can change due to external circumstances. I've seen cases on SU for example where the answer on how to do something is using software X, which was at the time freeware and compatible with usual operating systems. There were cases when the old versions of software are unavailable or not compatible and the new version isn't available under same conditions as the old one. That would be reason enough to remove up-vote.

Comment: Anyway, for those who can edit, this trick works (or at least it did sometime last year): Make a small edit to the answer. After that, you can vote on the newly edited answer and then undo the edit. I used that one time when I accidentally down-voted an answer.

Comment: @AndrejaKo: When the answer changes, you can change your vote.

Comment: I'm with Olin: I want to have the privilege to change my mind at all times, for whatever reason. Locking is silly anyway, since a dummy edit is sufficient to circumvent it.